# Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-push

We have Vaadin Push enabled with @Push(transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR).
When UI detached, we see the below exception at the log.

Seems like it does not impact anything other than errors at the log. Do you know how to close the connection nicely so we do not fill the log with those errors?

Thank you in advance.

```
07:33:40.853 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.a.container.JSR356Endpoint/log
java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.registerFuture(WsSession.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:277)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:586)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:488)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:449)
        at org.atmosphere.container.version.JSR356WebSocket.close(JSR356WebSocket.java:142)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.close(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:860)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ArePushConnection.disconnect(AtmospherePushConnection.java:312)
        at com.basf.gb.cube.seq.vaadinui.MyVaadinUI.detach(MyVaadinUI.java:111)
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.setSession(UI.java:465)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.removeUI(VaadinSession.java:870)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService$1$1.run(VaadinService.java:481)
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.accessSynchronously(UI.java:1381)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService$1.run(VaadinService.java:469)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.runPendingAccessTasks(VaadinService.java:1835)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.unlock(VaadinSession.java:990)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.requestEnd(VaadinService.java:1356)
        at org.vaadin.spring.servlet.Vaadin4SpringServletService.requestEnd(Vaadin4SpringServletService.java:84)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1423)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(AppliclterChain.java:207)
        at org.vaadin.spring.http.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChaiter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
07:33:41.209 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG c.vaadin.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl/detach UI [com.basf.gb.cube.seq.vaadinui.MyVaadinUI@a27a41e] has been detached, destroying [UIBeanStore
[id=4df03526, name=UI:0]]
07:33:41.210 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore/destroy Destroying [UIBeanStore[id=4df03526, name=UI:0]]
07:33:41.211 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG c.v.s.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIStore/sessionDestroy Vaadin session has been destroyed, destroying [UIStore[id=36f84595, sessionId=55AF0F6E983B
2291A8F9DBE9AA370163]]
07:33:41.212 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG c.v.s.i.VaadinSessionScope$SessionAwareBeanStore/sessionDestroy Vaadin session has been destroyed, destroying [SessionAwareBeanStore[id=6275
7279, name=Session:55AF0F6E983B2291A8F9DBE9AA370163]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "UI detached"? When you close the browser window, the server side has no chance to know this and throws the message mentioned

Comment: No, not the browser window closing. it is when Vaadin UI is detached. For example when user logout.

Comment: Here is the Vaadin Ticket I found, but there is not any solution/workaround mentioned: https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/19376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Tomcat bug see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59014

please Upgrade to Tomcat version 8.0.33 or 7.0.69

Comment: Thank you for your reply Alexander.  We use Spring Boot 1.3.3 and it uses Tomcat 8 by default. Maybe I am wrong, I will check again.

We have the above exception when user logs off or other times when the current Vaadin UI is detached. That's why I feel like It is somehow related to Vaadin not closing the connection gently. As I said, I am not sure tough.

Comment: Yes, you are correct Alexander, It is a Tomcat bug indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander's answer is correct. You need to upgrade 8.0.33 to overcome this issue, and this is how I managed to change Tomcat version for Spring Boot and Gradle.

```
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
  }
  //Because of the websocket defect on tomcat, I comment out the below line 
  //providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.33'
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.0.33'
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.0.33'
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.0.33'
```

Comment: Using Maven you can simply set the property `<tomcat.version>8.0.33</tomcat.version>`.  Not sure if something similar is possible using Gradle.

Comment: Apparently it is: see [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_use_tomcat_7_with_gradle).  Basically, add `ext['tomcat.version'] = '8.0.33'`